# Check number string start with 00 or 0

Tags: java, arrays, string

is there a optimized way to identify a number string start with Single zero, double or triple zero.

```
For eg: 01234 -- Single zero
001234 -- double
00023232 -- triple.
```

I know that, one way is traversing one by one based on the position and check its zero or not. But apart from this, is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to identify which of the cases it is (single, double, tripple), not just that it fits one of them or not?

Comment: i want to know that, number start with single zero or multiple zeros... thats all

Comment: how is that different from "the number starts with one zero"?

Comment: I need to check number is local number or International, if its single then its Local. double means international

Comment: You could also cast to a numeric value, next cast it back to a string, then subtract length of this string from the length of the original string.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that, one way is traversing one by one based on the position and check its zero or not. But apart from this, is there a better [more optimal] way?

No, looping would be the easiest and fastest way I would think to count leading zeros.

This code counts up to max of three as that seems to be what you want:

```
public static int leadingZerosCount(String s){
   int zeros=0;
   for(int i=0;i<3 && i<s.length();i++) {
      if(s.charAt(i)=='0')
        zeros++;
      else
        break;
   }
   return zeros;
}
```

## Regex version and tests

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0]{0,3}");

public int leadingZeros(String numberString) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(numberString);
    matcher.find();
    return matcher.group().length();
}

@Test
public void empty(){        
    assertEquals(0, leadingZeros(""));
}

@Test
public void none(){     
    assertEquals(0, leadingZeros("1"));
}

@Test
public void one(){      
    assertEquals(1, leadingZeros("01"));
}

@Test
public void two(){      
    assertEquals(2, leadingZeros("001"));
}

@Test
public void three(){        
    assertEquals(3, leadingZeros("0001"));
}   

@Test
public void more_than_three(){      
    assertEquals(3, leadingZeros("00001"));
}

@Test
public void two_but_not_leading(){      
    assertEquals(0, leadingZeros("1001"));
}
```

Comment: @Naruto You might want the version with no regex. The regex version  is 6 or 7 times slower than the non-regex version.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the 'startsWith' method of the String class:

```
boolean startWithZeros(String str, integer countOfZeroes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for( integer i = 0; i < coutOfZeroes; i++ )
    sb.append("0");
    return str.startsWith(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: So they must call this 3 times to work out if it is 1,2 or 3. And the program must build up the same simple `"0"`,  `"00"`,  `"000"` constants every time.

Comment: I just give a way to check for the leading zeroes without traversing the string manually (and without regex as I think it is far too heavy for this light task). The fastest way is to scan the leading zeroes directly. If you need it frequently, you will have to optimize it by caching patterns and adapt to your data if you know it will more often start with multiple zeroes than just 1 zero for instance.